# How can I include pug templates in compiled typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, pug

My nodejs based application uses Pug for rendering; specifically, i set the view engine and then set the view directory (which lives inside of the `src` directory that all other source lives in.

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
[...]
res.render('login')
```

This works correctly for the development version, which simply runs and interprets the typescript file that the above code is in. However, I would like to compile to javascript in production, and have the following (seemingly standard) typescript configuration:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "outDir":"./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src"
    },
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Recommended",
    "files": ["src/index.ts"],
}
```

Which reflects the directory structure of my code:

[image: the directory structure of my source code.]

Unfortunately, this fails to work when the application is compiled and ruins index.js; it cannot find the .pug files in `/dist/views`:
`Error: Failed to lookup view "posts" in views directory "/app/dist/views"`

I understand the error message, but not how to fix the problem. Should I be copying the templates to that folder as part of the build process? Should I be invoking them in another way that the compiler can 'understand' and include? Is compiling typescript to javascript simply an obsolete build step entirely?

Answer (score 2):

```js
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

This line configures Express to load the templates from the `views` folder, located in [the same place as the executed script](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#__dirname) (which would be `/dist` in that case).

The options are:

- Configure the build to copy the templates to `/dist/views`.
- Change the path settings, and put for example all `.ts` sources in `/src`, view templates in `/views` and configure `app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');` so it would be seen from `/src` as well as from `/dist`.
- Or skip the build step altogether and use [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), it can execute your `.ts` files directly.

edit: Bundling template scripts with the compiled `.js` file would only make sense or be useful if the bundle had to be sent to a Web browser, but as Express applications typically run server-side and *not* in a browser, Express does not support such a handling.

Answer (score 2):

**Copy non-typescript files to outDir**

---

I was facing the same problem but there is just a simple solution to get all non-ts files in your build folder

[here the package I used Typescript-cp](https://github.com/body-builder/typescript-cp)

```
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc -w & tscp -w",
    "build": "tsc && tscp"
  },
  //...
}
```

it will copy all your non-ts files in the build folder but you can specify which one to copy I think **read Docs**